# Problems buying the game on official site

Tags: diablo-iii

I visited the [official Diablo 3 site](http://www.diablo3.com/) to buy the game. I clicked on "Buy Diablo 3" button and it asked me to create a new account on Battle.net. I did it but now I cannot see how can I buy it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you're best off using the battle.net help and links as opposed to gaming.SE, tbh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Battle.net can be a little obtuse (I had to click "Buy Diablo 3 Now!" three times before it finally got to the appropriate page, including an add to buy Diablo 3 after clicking... "Buy Diablo 3"...) so I have a quick visual guide for ya:

First, log in to Battle.net, and go to the Account Summary page (you may need to provide your credentials a second time; don't worry, that's expected).
[image]
From here, click on the "Buy Digital Games" link on the far right. Do so.

[image]

It will take you to this page, where you can simply click "buy now" to start your purchase. (I'm unable to do so again because I've already done so, and there's a 1 game / account limit)

Comment: Thanks!! I couldn't see the buy option in the summary tab, because I didn't activated my email. Now I can see it. :)